# SQL LIKE with NCHAR returning records it shouldn't, why?

Tags: sql, unicode, sql-like, nchar

Why is the third row being returned even though it does not have the Unicode 8239 (narrow non-breaking space) in its contents?

```
DECLARE @tst as TABLE
(
    col NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @tst VALUES(CONCAT(N'this',NCHAR(8239),N'is a test'))
INSERT INTO @tst VALUES(N'this' + NCHAR(8239) + N'is another test')
INSERT INTO @tst VALUES(N'thisshouldnotbereturned')
SELECT * FROM @tst WHERE col LIKE N'%' + NCHAR(8239) + N'%'
```

I confirmed the first two records have Unicode 8239 (0x202F) inside. The third doesn't.

Comment: That character is a typesetter's "thin", a narrow non breaking space, FWIW.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code is product specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of your collation - some collations ignore this for operations such as Charindex and Like.

The default English collation *SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS* acts like this, however newer collations (containing "_100_" in the name) support it.

Eg if you try with the collation `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS` it should work as expected.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tkDjQDHB)